# HTML form validation to validate first letter of input in "pattern" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my input tag:

```
<input class="nameInput" type="text" id="nameIdValue" required 
        pattern="[\sa-zA-Z0-9'\.]$">

<div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine || name.required" class="alert 
alert-danger">
<div [hidden]="!name.hasError('required')">
  <small>{{name_mandatory}}</small>
</div>
<div [hidden]="!name.hasError('pattern')">
  <small>{{alphabets_only}}</small>
</div>
```

In this i need to validate the first letter of the input should be alphabet. But how to do in the pattern attribute in input tag. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Validation in name:
First letter of input should be alphabet.
Name should accepts alphabets, numbers and special characters like (dot), (single quote) and white space.

Comment: If you just want the first letter to be alpha, try `^[a-z].*`

Comment: Edited my post. Please check the validation points.